# How can I determine a file's conventional filename extension

Tags: shell, filenames, mime-types

The `file` command is good at determining file types for my needs. Is there any way to map those results to conventional filename extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file extensions registered on your system should be in `/etc/mime.types`. So, assuming you managed to extract the file type from the output of `file` into a variable called `type`, you can simply:

```
grep -i "$type" /etc/mime.types | awk '{$1="";print $0}'
```

or (as suggested by 200_success in the comments), you can use `awk` alone:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/ENVIRON["type"]/{$1="";print $0}'
```

**Example**

```
$ type=Perl
$ grep -i "$type" /etc/mime.types | awk '{$1="";print $0}'
 pl pm
```

Comment: `grep | awk` can usually be done using `awk` alone.

Comment: @200_success Please see the edited answer.

Comment: @200_success yes but that is not always a good idea since `grep` will tend to be faster than an `awk` that has to check a regex for each line.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same basic idea as @hildred's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102643/22222) but using a simpler approach (`gawk`) and modified to deal with file names containing spaces and unknown file types.

Add these lines to your shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc` for example, if you are running `bash`):

```
get_ext(){
 for f in "$@"; do 
  type='unknown extension';
  foo=$(grep -w "$(file --mime-type "$f" | awk '{print $NF}')" /etc/mime.types | 
  awk -F"\t" 'NF>1{print $NF}')
  [ -n "$foo" ] && type="$foo";
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$f" "$type";
 done    
}
```

You can now run it like this:

```
$ get_ext *
cp  unknown extension
file with spaces .jpg   jpeg jpg jpe
foo.pl  pl pm
foo.png png
foo.py  py
foo.txt asc txt text pot brf srt
```

It will return 'unknown extension' for files that have no associated extension in `/etc/mime.types` such as `cp` which is an executable.

Answer (score 2):

proof of concept, does not handle funny characters, assumes first extension is right.

```
file --mime-type -N *|sed \
   -e 's!^\(.*: \)\(.*\)$!echo \1;grep -e \2 /etc/mime.types!e' \
   -e 's!\n.*/[^     ]\+[    ]\+\([^ ]\+\).*! \1!' \
   -e 's!\n\(.*/[^     ]\)\+!\1!'
```

Comment: also assumes gnu sed